# RecyclerView can’t load an image of banner and data listitem

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

The  RecycleView lives in a in Fragment.
it has a banner as headview and listitem.
The app can run,but can't load images and data of item.
It only  has  the  banner of INDICATOR and  its img title to run.
The logcat warns about it:

```
18204-18204/newsdaily.annle.com.happyreading_original2018718v0013
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by
android.view.View{945cd0e V.ED..... ......ID 9336,141-9564,150}
during layout: running second layout pass
```

---

```
        package newsdaily.annle.com.**.homepage;

        import com.youth.banner.Banner;
        import com.youth.banner.BannerConfig;
        import com.youth.banner.Transformer;
        import com.youth.banner.listener.OnBannerListener;
        import com.youth.banner.loader.ImageLoader;


    public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {
        private HomePagerArticleAdapter homePagerArticleAdapter;
        private RecyclerView recycleView;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        private ArrayList<HpItemArticle> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

        private Banner banner;
        private ArrayList<String> titles;
        private ArrayList<Integer> images;

        private View header;

        private View view;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.homepage_list_fragment, container, false);
            Log.i("dfdfff开始", "有没有进入");
            initData();
            initRecycleView();
            return view;

        }


        private void initData() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                HpItemArticle hpItemArticle = new HpItemArticle(
                        i,
                        "数据标题" + i,
                        "内容究竟是什么，我也不知道，就乱写先吧hhhhhhh" + i,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                articleList.add(i, hpItemArticle);

            }
            images = new ArrayList<>();
            images.add(R.drawable.pic0);
            images.add(R.drawable.pic1);
            images.add(R.drawable.pic2);
            titles = new ArrayList<>();
            titles.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                titles.add("第" + i + "张图片");
            }


        }


        private void initRecycleView() {
            recycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.homepage_rcv_article);

            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            initBanner();
            homePagerArticleAdapter = new HomePagerArticleAdapter(getContext());
            homePagerArticleAdapter.setmHeaderView(header);
            homePagerArticleAdapter.addListData(articleList);
            homePagerArticleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recycleView.setAdapter(homePagerArticleAdapter);
            layoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(false);
        }

        private void initBanner() {
            header = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homepage_news_header, null);

            banner = (Banner) header.findViewById(R.id.banner);
            //设置图片加载器
            banner.setImageLoader(new FragmentImageLoader());
            banner.setImages(images); 
            banner.setBannerTitles(titles);
            banner.isAutoPlay(true);
            //设置轮播时间
            banner.setDelayTime(1500);
            banner.start();

            banner.setOnBannerListener(new OnBannerListener() {
                @Override
                public void OnBannerClick(int position) {
                    Log.i("---184--", "第" + position + "张轮播图点击了！");

                }
            });
        }


        private class FragmentImageLoader extends ImageLoader {

            @Override
            public void displayImage(Context context, Object path, ImageView imageView) {
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(path).into(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    package newsdaily.annle.com.**.adapter;



    /**
     * 首页新闻列表适配器，头部banner，下面文章列表
     * Created by 11581 on 2018/9/28.
     */

    public class HomePagerArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;


        private View homepageHeadView;


     te ArrayList<HpItemArticle> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

        private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            itemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        }

        public View getmHeaderView() {

            return homepageHeadView;
        }


        public void setmHeaderView(View headerview) {
            homepageHeadView = headerview;
            notifyItemInserted(0);//插入下标0位置

        }



        public int getTypeItem(int position) {

            if (homepageHeadView == null) return TYPE_ITEM;
            if (position == 0) return TYPE_HEADER;

            return TYPE_ITEM;

        }

        public HomePagerArticleAdapter(Context context) {
            mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }


        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            if (homepageHeadView != null && viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
                return new ItemArticleViewHolder(homepageHeadView);

            View view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homepage_news_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemArticleViewHolder(view);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_HEADER) return;

            final int pos = getPosition(holder);

            final HpItemArticle data = listData.get(pos);


            if (holder instanceof ItemArticleViewHolder) {
                //转型为了便捷

                ItemArticleViewHolder newHolder = (ItemArticleViewHolder) holder;

                newHolder.hpItemArticleTitle.setText(data.getTitle());
                newHolder.hpItemArticleImage.setImageResource(data.getImages());

                newHolder.hpItemArticleImage.setImageResource(data.getImages());

                if (itemClickListener == null) return;

                ((ItemArticleViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        itemClickListener.onItemClick(position, listData.get(position).getTitle());
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return homepageHeadView == null ? listData.size() : listData.size() + 1;
        }

        public int getPosition(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
            int position = holder.getLayoutPosition();
            return homepageHeadView == null ? position : position - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public void addListData(ArrayList<HpItemArticle> datas) {

            if (datas != null) {
                listData.clear();

            }
            listData.addAll(datas);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public class ItemArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView hpItemArticleImage;
            TextView hpItemArticleTitle;

            TextView hpItemArticleDetails;

            public ItemArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                if (itemView == homepageHeadView) return;

                hpItemArticleImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hp_item_article_image);
                hpItemArticleDetails = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hp_item_article_details);
                hpItemArticleTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hp_item_article_title);

                ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            }

        }

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(int position, String data);
        }
    }
```

My English  is not good.Thanks in advance.

banner.xml. header of RecyclerView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <com.youth.banner.Banner
             android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

RecyclerView item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hp_item_article_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hp_item_article_image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hp_item_article_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/homepage_article_title"

            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hp_item_article_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/homepage_article_details" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post Your Banner Class? Whats is Banner Class?

Comment: i  post banner'xml  ,because  it is a third  library

Comment: i think you are making it wrost...your glide class should be in adapter to apply image for each path.also your model List should be in constructor of your adapter and apply it in.you are getting empty data

Comment: I try to do it again。it work！！Thanksss!

Comment: nice.your welcome